# How to handle the spacing around units (such as MB, GB, CM, KM/H) in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I am indexing documents where the following types of text is common:

- 20m high | 20 m high
- 20GB of data | 20 GB of data
- 14oz of fluid | 14 oz of fluid

When someone searches for `20m` it doesn't match `20 m` and visa-versa.

Is there a tokenizer or filter which handles this issue? I would assume it would take a list of predefined units to match.

If there isn't already a tokenizer or filter, how would I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the additional **[solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory)** will help.  And the option to look for is

```
splitOnNumerics="1"
```

It will split the "**20m**" as "**20**", "**m**"